# MySql Sum with two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have two tables

`t1`

```
id  Name    Total
1   Alex    100
2   Bob     100 
1   Alex    100
```

`t2`

```
id  Amount 
1   2   
1   3   
1   4   
2   12  
2   13
```

I need to get sum of Total and Amount.

```
**select Name, sum(Total) as Total, sum(Amount) as Amount,day
from t1,t2
Where t1.id=t2.id
group by Name**
```

Result:

```
Alex 600    18 
Bob  200    25
```

Incorrect sum of Amount!

```
**select Name, sum(distinct Total) as Total, sum(Amount) as Amount,day
from t1,t2
Where t1.id=t2.id
group by Name**
```

Result:

```
Alex100 18

Bob 100 25
```

Incorrect sum of Amount.

MySql use distinct by value, i need distinct by id
corect result that need be is

```
 Alex 200 18  
 Bob  100 25
```

How to get to this result?

Comment: sum(distinct Total) will sum just the distinct Total values. If two rows have the value 5, only one of them will be included in the SUM. This is not what you want, remove DISTIONCT.

Comment: 1 Alex 100
2 Bob 100
1 Alex 100

Comment: Table t1 is 
id Name Total
1 Alex 100
2 Bob 100
1 Alex 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.Name, 
       sum(t1.Total) as Total, 
       sum(t2.Amount) as Amount,
       day
from t1
left join 
(
  select id, sum(Amount) as Amount
  from t2
  group by id
) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.Name
```